TeamCity's Finish Build Trigger is only triggered by builds in the default branch
I've seen many posts around this topic. Unfortunately, none of them seem to address the issue I have.
Take BCA (Build Config A) and BCB (Build Config B), for example.
BCA's default branch is ‘develop’, but it also has ‘staging’ and ‘master’ branches being built in TeamCity.BCB's default and only branch is ‘master’. BCB is a test config that should run after successful BCA builds.
I have the following trigger on BCB:
Finish Build Trigger.
Wait for a successful build in: BCA.
Branch filter:
    +:develop
    +:staging
    +:master

BCB builds trigger successfully and as expected when BCA builds complete successfully on BCA's develop (default) branch.However, no BCB build is triggered when BCA builds complete successfully on BCA's staging/master (non-default) branches.
What am I missing here?I would like BCB builds to trigger for BCA builds that complete successfully on staging and master branches as well, as we are expected to run those tests against BCA builds in those branches too.
